# Remove line breaks followed by space in text file

Tags: bash, file, replace, tr, line-endings

I have a text file that contains data that I am trying to make more easily readable. Some of the lines, e.g. info 2 below, have the results over multiple lines, where there is a line break followed by a number of spaces (see below).

```
info 1 : holiday
info 2: today the weather is very \n\r
       hot
```

I would like to remove all line breaks where there is a line break followed by a space. I have tried using

```
tr '\n\r ' '   ' < test.txt
```

but this removes all line endings. Is there a way to remove only those line endings followed by a space? I have quite a number of small files which I want to loop over.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

`tr` is for TRanslating **characters**. It replaces characters in the first set for characters in the second set. This is a set of characters, the order of characters in the set do not matter (that much) for tr.

> Is there a way

Yes, you have to *match* a newline followed by spaces and remove them. Note that most unix tools work on newlines, you have to use tools that work on the whole file. For example, with GNU sed:

```
sed -z 's/\n\r      //'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I get the error that -z is an illegal option, is this something to do with versions?

Comment: `with GNU sed:` You do not have GNU sed. You have a different sed, most probably from BSD.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
cat your_file | tr "\r\n" "#" | sed -e "s/# \+/ /g" | tr "#" "\n"
```

replace "#" on any symbol, that not exists in your text

Answer (score 1):

Using perl:

```
perl -p0e  's/ *\r\n +/ /g' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sed` for this

```
$ sed ':a;N;s/\(\\n\\r\)\?\n \+\(.*\)/\2/;ba' input_file
info 1 : holiday
info 2: today the weather is very hot
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read all lines into the pattern space, and then match the newline `\n\r` and capture at least a single space in a group.

In the replacement the backreference `\1` to the captured space.

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\n\r\([[:blank:]]\)/\1/g' file
```

Output after the replacement:

```
info 1 : holiday
info 2: today the weather is very       hot
```